# iPad simulator 5.1 shows blank white screen in Xcode 4.3

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4, ios-simulator

Guys. Please help me.. I've searched everywhere, but couldn't find a solution.

I'm using Xcode 4.3.2 and have the IOS 5.1 simulator installed.

The problem is the iPad simulator doesn't show the iPad's frame, just the contents. So, the home button isn't visible, thus can't be pressed.

But, unlike the iPad simulator, the iPhone simulator works fine.

Please help, guys..

Thank you

Comment: Try scrolling up. That happened to me and I have a hard time realizing that was because of my MBP resolution. Retina Display on iPad is just amazing.

Answer (score 4):

Use <kbd>⇧</kbd> +  <kbd>⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>h</kbd> in place of the home button.

If you need to make the screen smaller, use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for the smallest and smaller screen sizes respectively.

Comment: Any idea why it disappears like this?  I've been having this problem too (though I simply use the button combo to press it).  Once in a while the home button reappears too....

Comment: It disappears because the iPad (reg and ret.) and iPhone (ret.) sims are just too large to have bezels.

Comment: Thanks for answering guys.. I was having this problem after upgrading to Xcode 4.3.2 from Xcode 4.1.
I tried reducing the iPad simulator all the way down incrementally to 50%, but it didn't show the full iPad frame like the previous Xcode 4.1.
Does this mean that Apple has intentionally omitted displaying the iPad's frame in the iPad simulator?

Comment: Yes, it is intentional.  Now that they have 4 simulators with 2 configurable options and a variable number of OSes, it is impractical to have a bezel image.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I (and a colleague) have been seeing intermittent behavior, with the bezel sometimes showing up, and sometimes not, for the very same project (same version of iOS - 5.1, same build settings, etc).  This happens even when simulator is set to show a normal (non-retina) iPad... sometimes it has the bezel, sometimes not.

So I doubt this is intentional design.... seems like a bug to us.......